# How many Shaivite commentaries on the Brahma Sutras are there?

Tags: philosophy, vedanta, brahma-sutras, shaivism, sects

As I discuss in [this question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3193/36), by far the most popular school of Hindu philosophy is the Vedanta school, which bases its tenets on the doctrines laid out in the Brahma Sutras, a work by the sage Vyasa that summarizes and systematizes the philosophical teachings of the Upanishads. You can read the Brahma Sutras [here](http://www.advaita.it/library/brahmasutras2.htm); they consist of concise aphorisms, so people usually read them with the help of a commentary.  The oldest surviving  commentary on the Brahma Sutras is the Brahma Sutra Bhashya written by the Advaita Acharya Adi Shankaracharya.  And then there are numerous commentaries written by Vaishnava Acharyas, including the Sri Bhashya by the Sri Vaishnava Acharya Ramanujacharya, the Govinda Bhashya by the Gaudiya Vaishnava Acharya Baladeva Vidyabhushana, and the commentaries of Madhvacharya, Vallabhacharya, and Nimbarka.

But my question is, what Shaivite commentaries on the Brahma Sutras are there?  In my question [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8872/36), I discussed the Srikantha Bhashya, written by Srikantha Sivacharya (aka Nilakantha Sivacharya) who belonged to the Shaiva Siddhanta sect. You can read it [here](https://archive.org/details/TheVedantaSutrasWithSriKanthaBhashya). And in my answer [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/6621/36), I discuss the Shrikara Bhashya, written by Shripati who belonged to the Lingayat sect of Shaivism.  I don't have a copy of his commentary, so if anyone has it I'd appreciate it

But are these the only two Shaivite commentaries on the Brahma Sutras?  The reason I ask is that as I discuss [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8872/36), there's a section of the Brahma Sutras that seem to be refuting the philosophy of the Shaiva Agamas, so I'm wondering how different Shaivite commentators interpret that section.   (I posted a question about that [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/10235/36).)  Srikantha interprets it as refuting those who misinterpret this Shaiva Agamas, rather than criticizing the actual teachings of the Shaiva Agamas.  Perhaps others make sense of Vyasa's criticism of the Shaiva Agamas in a different way.  (By the way, Vaishnava have a somewhat analogous issue which I discuss [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9471/36).)

Now it's true that philosophical Shaivism went into decline after the time of Adi Shankaracharya, because the Vedanta school became dominant and a lot of Shaivite sects were not affiliated with the Vedanta school.  But aren't there other Shaivite sects which subscribe to Vedanta, and if so what commentaries on the Brahma Sutras have they written?

Answer (score 2):

I know of two. One is already referenced by means of a link in your question (Srikantha's).

And the other one is Srikara's bhashyam [here](https://archive.org/details/TheSrikaraBhashyaBeingTheVirasaivaCommentaryOnTheVedantaSutras/page/n2)

Since their philosophy is a bit different from older Vedantic schools, I doubt there are many bhashyams of Virshaiva schools on Brahma Sutras, but I am not sure.

If you find any please share with me. Thanks in advance