# Are there any proof of Moksha

Tags: moksha, rebirth, afterlife

Moksha is a concept, just like life after death & re-birth. We have various incidents where some child remembers things about previous life. Looking at these incidents we conclude that there may be life after death. 
Can anyone provide similar proofs that any human being has attained Moksha? Any sign, any scriptures providing signs of proof that a human being has attained Moksha after his death?

Comment: what you mean by Proof in this context?

Comment: @WhisperingMonk- I have edited the question for you. Thank you.

Comment: There are countless stories in scripture which describes Moksha attained by various humans... but don't know whether this becomes a proof for you or not...

Comment: Yes, if you ever got the blessing to associate yourself with a Self-realized Saint, then you will at once realize the peace of mind, the complete control over one's senses, the absolute bliss and the incredible love that emanate from a Saint of such realization. Such saints (Sri Ramakrishna, for example) are living examples. All the best

Comment: Examples like what? Yes i have known a few Saints but the self realization & other qualities that you are talking about is their qualities, which they have developed & preached. But all that does not prove that they have attained Moksha. Correct me if i am wrong, Ramakrishna is a great example, how can you say that he has attained Moksha ? Can he not been born in a different human or animal form in his next birth?

Comment: Why wait until death? Why not while living? The proof of moksha is in one's own direct perception of It. Until then it is all indirect. Anyone else's perception of moksha is no help to you. Only your own direct perception will help you. The way to perceive It is through hearing (sravanam), reflecting (mananam), and meditating (nididhyasanam).

Comment: What you are saying is the path of rightousness, the same things that any Hindu scripture talks about the correct way of leading a life. But Moksha or liberation from the cycle of birth & death is something else. Please enlighten me.

Comment: @Tezz, please inform me about some of the stories.

Comment: @SudipS story of Shabari, story of Kamsha, Ayodhyavaasi, Guha, Muchukunda, Ghantakarna (waiting but fixed after present Indra), story of Jatayu (even bird), story of Shuka (Vyasas son), etc... see Shanti Parva chapter 320 there Story of Suka attaining moksha is described.. http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/12137/how-do-dvaitins-and-vishistadvaitins-interpret-this-passage-of-mahabharata full story is in this chapter : http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12c033.htm

Comment: @Tezz, as you rightly said earlier, these stories are just stories & can't be taken as proof of attaining Moksha. Thanks anyways, i will be delighted to hear more from you on the subject. :-)

Comment: @SudipS if you want 100% proof then realize yourself... this is the only way... Practice Advaita Philosophy... snd slowly you will finally become JeevanMukta through in this very birth... All the Best...

Comment: @SudipS if you are interested in Advaita Philosophy... you can see my answer here.. http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/11295/what-is-the-position-of-mayaillusion-as-per-advaita-doctrine-or-according-to/12347#12347 and here:http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/11149/according-to-shankaracharya-in-advaita-is-the-universe-unreal-or-unworthy/13596#13596

Comment: @SudipS Good question. This subject is extremely deep and lengthy. So we will discuss more in chat if you're interested. However in short, as Swamiji says, in a strict sense, there is no proof for Moksha. However, the saints act as guides, to show you that they have attained JivanMukti (Liberated while alive). Moksha is not necessarily about freedom from rebirth, but rather freedom from body consciousness.

Comment: Have you came across Gajendra Moksham?  The elephant will offer lotus daily to Lod. Even now Guruvayurappan s holding a lotus in his hand. When the crocodile caught the leg of Gajendra it aksed for help with its relatives the elephantherd. No other elephants came for rescue. Gajendran thought only Lord is the source. Immediately it screamed Aadhimoolame - the lord killed the crocodile with his chakra and gave moksha to gajendran.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no signs or proofs that a person has attained moksha after death to the ordinary person. Similarly, there is no sign or proof that a living man has attained moksha. In his *Pancadasi*, Sri Vidyaranya Swami says (VI. 287-288):

> Enlightened  men may differ in their behavior because of the nature of their fructifying Karma. This should not make the learned think otherwise about the truth of knowledge resulting in liberation.
>
> Let the enlightened people behave in any way according to their fructifying Karma, but their knowledge is the same and their liberation is the same.

and in his commentary on the first verse, verse 287, Swami Swahananda says:

> There is no uniform rule about how a knower will behave. A well-known verse says: 'Krishna lived a life of enjoyment, Suka renounced even before Vedic initiation, vast empires were ruled by Rama and Janaka and Vasistha was a great ritualist, but all of them had the same illumination.'

And in the *Introduction* to Swami Swahananda's translation of the *Pancadasi*, T.M.P. Mahadevan says:

> The final court of appeal is experience,--the plenary experience, which is the fruit of inquiry. In fact, the texts of scripture are but indicators of that experience. Thus, in Vedanta, the nature of Truth is sought to be expounded on the triple basis of scripture [hearing], reasoning [reflecting], and experience [meditating] (*srutyuktyanubhutibhyah*, V, 56, & XI, 89).

Comment: Vivekananda, Very nice answer. Though it does not answer my question directly, this is by far the nearest one can get to understanding Moksha. You see, i think the same way, no 2 persons are the same, hence their thoughts, experiences & sense of enlightenment can not be same. Hence the concept of Moksha has to be different for both. As far as the 'leaving the birth-death cycle' is concerned, i think that is a myth which no one can prove. The theory of evolution can be a clue to this mystery.

Comment: "sense of enlightenment can not be same" It is same, read the above verse, it says realized beings may behave differently but all of them had the "same illumination".

Comment: Nice answer! Indeed, there is no symptoms or "fixed" way/situation related to Moksha. An exact Gita sloka is related to this states that: "Even learned (intelligents) men also act according to their modes of material nature, then why to have reservations?"

Answer (score 2):

I am posting below Swami Vivekananda’s initial experiences reported by Swami Nikhilananda’s introductory essay in his book ‘The Gospel of Sri Ramakrishna’.

> During his second visit, about a month later, suddenly, at the touch
>   of the Master, Narendra felt overwhelmed and saw the walls of the room
>   and everything around him whirling and vanishing. "What are you doing
>   to me?" he cried in terror. "I have father and mother at home." He saw
>   his own ego and the whole universe almost swallowed in a nameless
>   void. With a laugh the Master easily restored him. Narendra thought he
>   might have been hypnotized, but he could not understand how a
>   monomaniac could cast a spell over the mind of a strong person like
>   himself.    But during his third visit Narendra fared no better. This
>   time, at the Master's touch, he lost consciousness entirely. ....   A
>   few more meetings completely removed from Narendra's mind the last
>   traces of the notion that Sri Ramakrishna might be a monomaniac or
>   wily hypnotist. ...   ..Narendra, because of his Brahmo upbringing,
>   considered it wholly blasphemous to look on man as one with his
>   Creator. One day at the temple garden he laughingly said to a friend:
>   "How silly! This jug is God! This cup is God! Whatever we see is God!
>   And we too are God! Nothing could be more absurd." Sri Ramakrishna
>   came out of his room and gently touched him. Spellbound, he
>   immediately perceived that everything in the world was indeed God. A
>   new universe opened around him. Returning home in a dazed state, he
>   found there too that the food, the plate, the eater himself, the
>   people around him, were all God. When he walked in the street, he saw
>   that the cabs, the horses, the streams of people, the buildings, were
>   all Brahman. ..... It took him a number of days to recover his normal
>   self. He had a foretaste of the great experiences yet to come and
>   realized that the words of the Vedanta were true.

The Gospel of Sri Ramakrishna translated by Swami Nikhilananda

Comment: nice but how does it prove that Ramakrishna or Naren attained moksha after death?

Comment: Tezz has already stated the correct position that there are countless stories about humans attaining moksha but it is up to you to accept or reject such stories as proof. I just posted one such story. The claim is that Vivekananda got a tatse of moksha while he was alive.

Comment: I must criticize this foolish idea. If we were GOD, why can't we create miracles by ourselves? This is wrong theory , someone please remove it.

Comment: If your theory is true, make me fly like Lord Hanuman.

Comment: @ParthTrivedi There is a very large number of people who believe that we are God.  It's called Advaita, and it's the philosophy of Adi Shankaracharya and his followers.  And Advaitins have an explanation for why most people can't create miracles: it's because we still have Avidya and thus we don't realize our true nature.  Now I happen to disagree with Advaita (I believe in Ramanujacharya's philosophy of Visistadvaita), but there's certainly no reason to remove or flag posts just because they favor Advaita.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Theories are only abstract until implemented.