# Why some spiritual people become cynical?

Tags: spirituality

Why some spiritual people become cynical? Even though they know soul is ansha of GOD, they don't meet people, act as selfish person and meet in specific time. Why? When one really need guidance their doors are closed at the peak time. Then how can one get help?

Are they considering the seeker a part of Maya or they are diffident in helping him?

Comment: From [this answer](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/14457/1049): *Pancadasi*, Vidyaranya Swami says (VI. 287-288): *`Enlightened men may differ in their behavior because of the nature of their fructifying Karma. This should not make the learned think otherwise ... Let the enlightened people behave in any way according to their fructifying Karma, but their knowledge is the same ... There is no uniform rule about how a knower will behave. A well-known verse says: 'Krishna lived a life of enjoyment, Suka renounced even before Vedic initiation, vast empires were ruled by Rama and Janaka ...`*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is provided in Shreemad Bhagvat purana by Lord Shree Krishna.
He explains about "Vanaprastha" (वानप्रस्थ) and "Sanyasi Dharma."

In  these shlokas Lord Shree Krishna explains How a spiritual oriented person and Sadhus and Sanyasi's should behave who are  his pure devotee's.

> प्रसंग्ड:मजरं पाशमात्मणन: कवयो विदु:|
>  स एव साधुषु कृतो
>   मोक्षद्वारमपावृतम||२०||
>
> prasaṅgam ajaraṁ pāśam ātmanaḥ kavayo viduḥ sa eva sādhuṣu kṛto
>   mokṣa-dvāram apāvṛtam
>
> **Meaning** - Every learned man knows very well that attachment for the material is the greatest entanglement of the spirit soul. **But
>   that same attachment, when applied to the self-realized devotees,
>   opens the door of liberation.**   [**SB3.25.20**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/3/25/20)
>  
>   Here in this shloka it's told that the **selfishness or Asakti** which is unimpaired bondage of general people, the same Selfishness when  develops to Mahapurusha or Realised souls , it is indication of opened door to moksha for them.

---

> **बुधो बालकवत क्रिडेत कुशलो जड़चचरेत्।29।। 
>  वदेदुम्नत्तवद विद्वान् गोचर्या नैगमश्चरेत।।**
>
> Budho Balakvat kridet kushlo jadchhret  Vadedumnattavad vidwaan
>   gocharya naigamashret.
>
> **Meaning** - Even wise he should act like a child , even clever he should live like fool  , **even knower of vedas he should live like
>   animal.**
>
> ---
>
> **ज्ञाननिष्ठो विरक्तो वा मद्भक्तो वानपेक्षक:।** 
>  
>   **सलिङ्गनाश्रमांस्तयक्वता चरेविधिगोचर:।।28।।**
>
> GynaaNistho virakto va madbhakto vaanpekashkaha 
>   Salindgnashrmamstayakvata charevidhigochara
>
> **Meaning** - A learned transcendentalist dedicated to the cultivation of knowledge and thus detached from external objects, or My devotee
>   who is detached even from desire for liberation — both neglect those
>   duties based on external rituals or paraphernalia. **Thus their
>   conduct is beyond the** **range of rules and regulations.**
>
> [**Skanda 11, Chapter 18  Shloka 28-29**](http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/11/18/29)

Here shree krishna is telling us that a sadhu or spiritual person should not believe in this world , nor should he assume it's true.He should not engage his mind in any material thing , and even do not wish to do anything in any loka. And so i think that's  why some sadhus or Sanyasi's deliberately act like a Cynical , realising all this is maya.

Comment: 'cynical' means 'selfish and dishonest in a way that shows no concern about treating other people fairly', I don't think it means 'talk like a fool'. The verse you referenced is a good one but the translation could be better.

Comment: But this BG verse vindicate this,so i accept this answer, When GOD says it is Righteousness then we can not have objections.

Comment: @ParthTrivedi - Thanks , there is another verse , which is in the link ,I will add that also to make the answer more clear.

Answer (score 5):

#### Why do some spiritual people appear cynical? Why don't they meet people and socialize? Why don't they act "normal?"

One possible reason is, they are trying to curtail their senses by avoiding contact with other people. By trying to socialize and help others achieve their spiritual goals there is a chance they themselves are dragged back into the materialistic world and easily lose all the spiritual progress they made so far with a single misstep.

> 7.
>   Even advanced aspirants who have made great progress in Yoga should be very careful. They should not mix freely with ladies. They should not foolishly imagine that they have become great adepts in Yoga. **A great saint of repute had a downfall.** He freely mixed with ladies made lady disciples and allowed them to shampoo his legs. As the sex-energy was not completely sublimated and turned into Ojas, as lust was lurking in a subtle form in his mind, he became a victim. He lost his reputation. The sexual desire was only suppressed in him and when a suitable opportunity came, it again assumed grave form. **He had no strength or will-power to resist the temptation.**
>
> 8.
>   Another great soul who was regarded by his disciples as an Avatara became a Yoga-bhrashta. He also freely mixed with ladies and committed serious crimes. He became a prey to lust. What a sad misfortune! **Aspirants climb with great difficulty by the ladder of Yoga and they are irrecoverably lost for ever on account of their carelessness and spiritual pride.**

Reference: *[Easy Steps to Yoga](http://www.dlshq.org/download/easysteps.htm#_VPID_21)* by Swami Sivananda

Answer (score 2):

Because, **spirituality & cynicism are Not related**. Like how every sane human is not enlightened, similarly every enlightened human *needs* not be sane. Additionally, there is also no relation between sinful behavior and enlightenment/liberation. Numerous verses in Gita suggests the same. But for your answer, following are of interest (Gambhirananda's translations):

> <sub>BG 3.5 - Because, no one ever remains even for a moment without doing work. For all are made to work under compulsion by the gunas born of Nature.</sub>
>
> <sub>BG 3.33 - **Even a man of wisdom behaves according to [his] own nature**. Being follow [their] nature. What can restraint do?</sub>

One should avoid judging others by their mere behavior. That's the root of gossips, a major deviation. Rather it's always desirable to have a charitable view for everyone.
That helps one focus better towards almighty.

I don't defend those people who act in cynical or weird manner. Rather my point is not to relate those 2.
In any case rudeness, stubbornness, prideful-ness can't be signs of enlightened people. Because such qualities are binding qualities. Weirdness is just a trait.

---

From [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/14457/1049), Pancadasi, Vidyaranya Swami says (VI. 287-288):

> <sub>Enlightened men may differ in their behavior because of the nature of their fructifying Karma. This should not make the learned think otherwise ... Let the enlightened people behave in any way according to their fructifying Karma, but their knowledge is the same ... There is no uniform rule about how a knower will behave. A well-known verse says: 'Krishna lived a life of enjoyment, Suka renounced even before Vedic initiation, vast empires were ruled by Rama and Janaka ...</sub>