# Why do we worship Devas? Because they are immortal etc., ?

Tags: bhakti

The followers of Hindu religion generally worship Devas(Devtas), whereas we know that real creator of this world is Trideva, not Devas. And also we know that all Devas are son(next generation and furthermore) of sage Kashapya and Aditi. So my question are:-

1. Why are devas immortal? Whereas all creature take birth on earth(Marta)
   have to die one day. I said this because they are of generation from
   human.
2. Why is the responsibility of controlling  this world is reposed to
   them? Why don't we(human) have any responsibility?
3. And also Devas are created by Trideva like other creatures. So why do
   they have supernatural powers?

Update:- I asked about Devas in this post, not Trideva. So don't confuse with Trideva(Brahma, Vishnu, Shiva).

Comment: Your Q is having too many Qs.. Are u asking 1. Why we worship "lesser Gods" instead of worshipping only the Trinities? 2. Do we worship them because they are immortals? So, is immortality  a criteria that makes someone worship-worthy? -- Are these two ur main Qs?

Comment: @Rickross    I said that why we worship Devas, whereas Trideva are true creator of this world. And if we worship Devas(A Creature), then why we don't worship humans and other creature. Anyway, For your satisfaction, I am editing this post.

Comment: @user9344763 Your first  answer given by me here:— https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/24043/is-lord-ganesha-considered-same-as-the-ultimate-truth-and-reality-brahman/24045#24045 

 second question, third and fourth can be understand above but answer is given by me here:— https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/21787/why-god-viraat-purush-created-devatas-to-enjoy-and-humans-to-suffer/21789#21789

(It is based on vedas and upnishads)

Comment: @Fiercelord  Thanks a lot for further explanation. But the first question remains same. I am posting about it. Please satisfy my curiosity.

Comment: The title and body of question asking different things.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know the exact answer of other questions but the answer of the first question is quite simple.

The Devas are immortal because the drank [Amrita](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amrita) that was acquired by the Devas during [Samudra Manthan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samudra_manthan)

Here is some info of Amrita according to Wikipedia:-

> Amrit is repeatedly referred to as the drink of the devas which grants them immortality. Despite this the nectar does not offer true immortality. Instead, by partaking the nectar the gods were able to attain a higher level of knowledge and power, which they had lost due to the curse of Sage Durvasa.
>
> Amritha features in the samudra manthana legend, which describes how the devas, because of a curse from the sage Durvasa, begin to lose their immortality. Assisted by their mortal enemies, the asuras, they churn the ocean and release (among other auspicious object and beings) amritha, the nectar of immortality.[3]
>
> Amritha is sometimes said to miraculously form on, or flow from, statues of Hindu gods. The substance is consumed by worshippers and is alleged to be sweet-tasting and not at all similar to honey or sugar water.
>
> Amritha was the last of the fourteen treasure jewels that emerged from the churning of the ocean and contained in a pot borne by Dhanvantari, the physician of the Gods.