# Why Devas are worshiped by humans? Where all are one Brahman?

Tags: brahman, bhakti

I don't know that why Devas are worshiped by humans? In another word, it can be said that, they are worshiped by themselves. Because, We know that all thing, all creature of this world are one Brahman. So I can say that I am(Atman, not body) Devas and Devas is me. Because I am a part of Brahman, Devas and all creature are part of Brahman. Then if Devas is humans and humans is Devas, so why It became the low to worship Devas. And also there is no rules to worship humans, we only serve(seva) to them. Where humans are part of Brahman. Then why we can only worship to Devas, a part of Brahman, and we can't worship to humans, another part of Brahmans. And Vivekananda said, if you serve human, then you also served Brahman. And also it is said that if you worship Devas, they will bless you. But why? Why Devas bless us only if I worship him? whereas they are not above from *Karma*. And this is responsibility of Devas to serve Brahman. And they can serve Brahman by worship Trideva, by blessing humans. Then why it is needed to worship Devas to be blessed by them?

Note:- It is not duplicate of [this post](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/24265/13429). It is only Update of 1st Q of that post.

Comment: If you clarified the first question of other question in this post, the part from that question should be removed. The other question should focus on only one question than the multiple questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Brahman was this
>   before; therefore it
>   knew even the Ātma
>   (soul, himself). I am
>   Brahman, therefore it
>   became all. And
>   whoever among the
>   gods had this
>   enlightenment, also
>   became That. It is the
>   same with the sages,
>   the same with men.
>   Whoever knows the
>   self as “I am
>   Brahman,” becomes
>   all this universe. **Even
>   the gods cannot
>   prevail against him,
>   for he becomes their
>   Ātma. Now, if a man
>   worships another god,
>   thinking: “He is one
>   and I am another,” he
>   does not know. He is
>   like an animal to the
>   gods.** As many
>   animals serve a man,
>   so does each man
>   serve the gods. Even
>   if one animal is taken
>   away, it causes
>   anguish; how much
>   more so when many
>   are taken away?
>   Therefore it is not
>   pleasing to the gods
>   that men should know
>   this.
>
> **— [Brihadaranyaka
>   Upanishad 1.4.10](http://www.hinduwebsite.com/sacredscripts/hinduism/upanishads/brihad.asp)**

And nextly why we worship them because they all are brahmana:—

like in vedas indra was a prominent diety agni,soma,surya etc but others too are great and are never marked less.

[Which Vedic verses describe Indra as Brahman?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/19033/which-vedic-verses-describe-indra-as-brahman)

[Do any verses in the Vedas declare Agni to be supreme?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/22574/do-any-verses-in-the-vedas-declare-agni-to-be-supreme)

[Which scriptures or Vedic hymns declare the Sun as the Supreme God (Brahman)?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/21307/which-scriptures-or-vedic-hymns-declare-the-sun-as-the-supreme-god-brahman)

[Do any Vedic verses depict Lord Vishnu to be supreme?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/19872/do-any-vedic-verses-depict-lord-vishnu-to-be-supreme)

So its very common that gods apart from vedas apart every god is supreme in their texts or scriptues although all are supreme because all are one. :)

Now vedas declare it too:—

> 13 Glory to Gods, the mighty and
>   the lesser glory to Gods the
>   younger and the elder! Let us, if
>   we have power, pay the God
>   worship: no better prayer than
>   this, ye Gods, acknowledge.
>
> —[Rig veda 1.27.13](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv01027.htm)

Vedas say to give equal respect to
all gods.

> 46 **They call him Indra, Mitra,
>   Varuṇa, Agni, and he is heavenly
>   nobly-winged Garutmān.
>   To what is One, sages give many a
>   title they call it Agni, Yama,
>   Mātariśvan.**
>
> — [Rig Veda: Rig-Veda Book 1:
>   HYMN CLXIV. Viśvedevas:46](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv01164.htm)

Now  gods are discussed in brihadaranyaka upnishada :—

**NINTH BRAHMANA**

> 1. Then Vidagdha
>      Sakalya asked him: 'How
>      many gods are there, O
>      Yagnavalkya?' He replied
>      with this very Nivid: 'As
>      many as are mentioned
>      in the Nivid of the hymn
>      of praise addressed to
>      the Visvedevas, viz.
>      three and three
>      hundred, three and
>      three thousand.'
>      'Yes,' he said, and asked
>      again: 'How many gods
>      are there really, O
>      Yagnavalkya?'
>      'Thirty-three,' he said.
>      'Yes,' he said, and asked
>      again How many gods
>      are there really, O
>      Yagnavalkya?'
>      'Six,' he said.
>      'Yes,' he said, and asked
>      again:' How many gods
>      are there really, O
>      Yagnavalkya?'
>      'Three,' he said.
>      'Yes,' he said, and asked
>      again: 'How many gods
>      are there really, O
>      Yagnavalkya?'
>      'Two,' he said.
>      'Yes,' he said, and asked
>      again:'How many gods
>      are there really, O
>      Yagnavalkya?'
>      'One and a half
>      (adhyardha),' he said.
>      'Yes,' he said, and asked
>      again: 'How many gods
>      are there really, O
>      Yagnavalkya?'
>      'One,' he said.
>      'Yes,' he said, and
>      asked: 'Who are these
>      three and three
>      hundred, three and
>      three thousand?'
> 2. Yagnavalkya replied:
>      'They are only the
>      various powers of them,
>      in reality there are only
>      thirty-three gods.'
>      He asked: 'Who are
>      those thirty-three?'
>      Yagnavalkya replied:
>      'The eight Vasus,the
>      eleven Rudras, the
>      twelve Adityas. They
>      make thirty-one, and
>      Indra and Pragapati
>      make the thirty-three.'
>
> **3. He asked: 'Who are
>   the Vasus.'
>   Yagnavalkya replied:
>   'Agni (fire), Prithivi
>   (earth), Vayu (air),
>   Antariksha (sky), Aditya
>   (sun), Dyu (heaven),
>   Kandramas (moon), the
>   Nakshatras (stars), these
>   are the Vasus, for in
>   them all that dwells
>   (this world) rests; and
>   therefore they are called
>   Vasus.'**
>
> 4. **He asked: 'Who are
>      the Rudras?'
>      Yagnavalkya replied:
>      'These ten vital breaths
>      (pranas, the senses, i. e.
>      the five gnanendriyas,
>      and the five
>      karmendriyas), and
>      Atman, as the eleventh.
>      When they depart from
>      this mortal body, they
>      make us cry (rodayanti),
>      and because they make
>      us cry, they are called
>      Rudras.'**
> 5. **He asked: 'Who are
>      the Adityas?'
>      Yagnavalkya replied:
>      'The twelve months of
>      the year, and they are
>      Adityas, because they
>      move along (yanti),
>      taking up everything
>      (adadanah). Because
>      they move along, taking
>      up everything, therefore
>      they are called Adityas.'**
> 6. **He asked: 'And who is
>      Indra, and who is
>      Prajapati?'
>      Yagnavalkya replied:'
>      Indra is thunder,
>      Prajapati is the
>      sacrifice.'
>      He asked: 'And what is
>      the thunder?'
>      Yagnavalkya replied:
>      'The thunderbolt.'
>      He asked: 'And what is
>      the sacrifice?'
>      Yagnavalkya replied:
>      'The (sacrificial)
>      animals.'**
> 7. He asked: 'Who are
>      the six?'
>      Yagnavalkya replied:
>      'Agni (fire), Prithivi
>      (earth), Vayu (air),
>      Antariksha (sky), Aditya
>      (sun), Dyu (heaven), they
>      are the six, for they are
>      all this, the six.'
> 8. He asked: 'Who are
>      the three gods?'
>      Yagnavalkya replied:
>      'These three worlds, for
>      in them all these gods
>      exist.'
>      He asked: 'Who are the
>      two gods?'
>      Yagnavalkya replied:
>      'Food and breath.'
>      He asked: 'Who is the
>      one god and a half?'
>      Yagnavalkya replied: 'He
>      that blows.'
> 9. Here they say: 'How is
>      it that he who blows like
>      one only, should be
>      called one and a half
>      (adhyardha)?' And the
>      answer is: 'Because,
>      when the wind was
>      blowing, everything grew
>      (adhyardhnot).'
>
> He asked: 'Who is the
>   one god?'
>   Yagnavalkya replied:
>   'Breath (prana), and he
>   is Brahman (the
>   Sutratman), and they
>   call him That (tyad).'
>
> — [Brihadaranyaka upnishada:second adhyaye:brahmana 9](http://www.hinduwebsite.com/sacredscripts/hinduism/upanishads/brihad.asp)

Comment: I have understood it. Thanks for your explanation. But plz think about one thing. If a Deva, suppose Indra only think about his pleasure, then how he become Brahman? Because Brahman is not one, he is all and all is he(Brahman). In this way, he only the body, not true self, not Brahman. Then how you can say that Indra and all Devas is Brahman? Plz consider it.

Comment: @Fiercelord please edit the spellings of "Prajapati". Pragapati spelling may make people pronounce it as PaGApati only, which is incorrect.

Comment: Gods are forms of god in vedas in kena upnishad they wined because of brahmana and became proud brahmana tested their powers but all were outmatched when indra arrived he disappeared goddess uma told he was brahmana so,gods first came to know about him now,  a man as in my answer first verse says understand himself then gods also do not prevail against him because he is now their atman but **When understands** now vedas say all gods are form of brahmana so in vedas gods do not do a lot bad things vedas and purans are diffrent (Its my thinking you can believe in yourself @user9344763)

Comment: gods are parts of brahman and when they do something bad they are punished in purans. But they are forms of god like wothout air we could not live now you can think air as a god or part of one god its upto you.

Comment: @user9344763 it's ok friend yes a thought came in my mind regarding your question that "why humans are not worshiped,why we only serve them" then it is recommend to see god in all creatures then also we worship guru why? because he knew brahmana he is brahmana anybody who knows brahmana is brahmana but who does not is jiva having atman living inside but sometimes unknown.  As i said god is one regard him as one or as many. krishna ji too said gods are part of his body so i suggest that believe in one but respect others also as parts or same and never critisize anybody's god its an only advice.

Comment: These all are just advices believe in what you are got up with i just hope that my advices may help you afterall words are not above god.

Comment: No, I always respect all gods. I can say that I never neglect any gods. I asked this Q because of my curiosity, not for neglect. Anyway, thanks for advice.