# What references are there to Vamana's ancient Tika on the Brahma Sutras?

Tags: history, vedanta, vaishnavism, sri-vaishnava, brahma-sutras

As I discuss in [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3193/277) question, by far the most popular school of Hindu philosophy is the Vedanta school, which bases its tenets on the doctrines laid out in the Brahma Sutras, a work by the sage Vyasa which summarizes and systematizes the philosophical teachings of the Upanishads. (You can read the [**Brahma Sutras**](http://www.advaita.it/library/brahmasutras2.htm)  here.)  Now presently the oldest surviving commentary on the Brahma Sutras is the Brahma Sutra Bhashya composed by the Advaita philosopher Adi Shankaracharya.  But that is by now means the oldest commentary on the Brahma Sutras; there used to be many pre-Shankara commentaries which are now lost.

Now the Sri Vaishnava Acharya Ramanujacharya felt that Adi Shankaracharya had distorted the meaning of the Brahma Sutras, so in writing his commentary on the Brahma Sutras, known as the Sri Bhashya, he relied on the works of as many pre-Shankara commentators as could find.  [This excerpt](https://books.google.com/books/content?id=18caAAAAYAAJ&output=text&pg=PA629&img=1&zoom=3&hl=en&q=vamana+tikakara&cds=1&sig=ACfU3U0MTY4mwP5Hp0A1tZ2H5basAGrlXw&edge=0&edge=stretch&ci=0,0,998,1520) from a journal paper lists some of them:

> Bodhayana, the Vrittikara, was the first commentator on the Brahma Sutras, a well-known Rishi and a contemporary of Vyasa, from whom Sri Ramanuja makes quotation here and there. Then come Brahmanandi, the Vakyakara and Dramidacharya - the Bhashyakara, **Vamana - the Tikakara on Dramida Bhashya**, about whom references are made not only by Sri Ramanuja but also by Yamunacharya his predecessor and Sudarshanacharya who wrote an every wide and brilliant commentary on [Ramanujacharya's Sri Bhashya].

Now I'm aware of references in the works of Sri Vaishnava Acharyas and others to most of these figures.  I provide quotes from Baudhayana/Upavarsha, the Vrittikara, in my answer [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/14550/36). I provide a quote from Tanka/Brahmanandi, the Vakyakara, in my question [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9325/36).  And I provide a  quote from Dramidacharya, the Bhashyakara who wrote a commentary on Tanka's Vakya, in my answer [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/16560/36).  But my question is, what references are there to Vamana, the Tikakara who wrote a commentary on Dramidacharya's Bhashya?

Now the Dvaita philosopher Narayana Panditacharya lists Vamana as one of the 21 commentators who lived before the time of Madhvacharya, as you can see [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=FVtpFMPMulcC&lpg=PP1&dq=bnk%20sharma%2021%20commentators&pg=PA98#v=onepage&q&f=false).  But do the Sri Vaishnaava Acharyas Ramanujacharya, Yamunacharya, or Sudarshana Suri make any reference to Vamana's Tika as the journal paper suggests?  In [this excerpt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nakH.jpg) the Vedartha Sangraha, Ramanujacharya lists various pre-Shankara Vedantic philosophers:

> The philosophical approach herein is one that has been presented by the Vedas, whose import has been clearly revealed by the ancient commentaries on the Vedas and Vedanta and has been unanimously adopted by the great ones like Bhagavan Bodhayana, Tanka, Dramida, Guhadeva, Kapardin and Bharuchi.

So Vamana isn't mentioned, unless he's mentioned under a different names.  By the way, are there any surviving quotes from Vamana's Tika, just as the surviving quotes from Baudhayana's Vritti, Tanka's Vakya, and Dramidacharya's Bhashya?