# What is Madhvacharya's argument against Brahman being the material cause of the universe?

Tags: vedanta, atma, brahman, dvaita, madhvacharya

Madhvacharya is the proponent of the Dvaita school of Vedanta because he doesn't believe that Brahman is the material cause of Jivatmas and Prakriti.

But what is his main argument against it?

Comment: Well, Madhvacharya, like all members of the Vedanta school, believed that Sandra Pramana is the proper source of knowledge concerning Brahman.  So his argument might have been basically "the Upanishads declare that Brahman is the efficient cause and not the material cause of the Universe". The question is what Upanishad passages he used.

Comment: In my question [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/10296/36) I discuss how Shaiva Siddhantins (at least the ones who reject the Vedanta school) cite a Shwetashwatara Upanishad verse to argue Brahman is not the material cause.  Madhvacharya might have cited the same verse.  Alternatively, Madhvacharya might have thought that Brahman being the efficient cause is known through Sabda Pramana, but Prakriti being the material cause is known through Anumana.  At least the Samkhya and Yoga schools thought Prakriti being the material cause is known through Anumana.

Comment: Ramanuja gives tries hard to refute the notion of the world being unreal, so Madhva might do the same.

Comment: Regarding Brahman not being the material cause.

Comment: Better to read his commentaries and other dwaita scholars

Comment: @keshavSrinivasan i was reading Madhwa bhashya on 1.4th pada. He says Brahman is prakriti...prakriti is brahman(1.4.24 nd 25)....He doesn't sound dvaitin to me.