# Is every being a God?

Tags: philosophy, gods, upanishads, brahman

According to [Kaivalya Upanishad](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/kaivalya-upanishad/d/doc120060.html):

> He(Supreme Brahman) alone is all that was,  and all that will be,  the
>   Eternal.  Knowing Him,  one transcends death.  There is no other way
>   to freedom.

We know Supreme Being is God. As stated below from [Kaivalya Upanishad](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/kaivalya-upanishad/d/doc120059.html).

> He is God,  He is The Absolute,  He is Heaven,  He is Eternal,  the
>   Supreme,  the Self-luminous,  He alone is All,  He is Breath,  He is
>   Time and Fire,  He is the Moon.

If God alone is all that was,and all that will be , then isn't every being a God?
Isn't every act an act of God ? Isn't every speech an speech of God?

Comment: yes god ....... however this is non vedic upanishad

Comment: I am not God. :-)

Comment: it depend on your definition of god.. once you are aware of your innerself you will find yourself nonseparate from god.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I want scripture-based explanation for "God is Everywhere"](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/11529/i-want-scripture-based-explanation-for-god-is-everywhere)

Comment: yes, but not your ego - that which your mind identifies as 'you'. You must go deeper.

Comment: Another duplicate: [Is every Jeeva "eternal" like the ultimate God (nirguna Brahman) or "temporary" within cycle?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/11038/1049). Refer the Gita verse in the accepted answer.

Comment: सर्वं खल्विदं ब्रह्म |

Answer (score 4):

Every being infact every thing is Brahman.

> "You are the woman, You are the man, You are the boy, (and) You are
>   the girl too. You are the old man tottering with a stick. Taking
>   birth, You have Your faces everywhere."

(Svetasvatara Upanishad 4.3)

> "You, indeed, are the blue bee; You indeed are the green  parrot
>   having red eyes; You indeed are possessed of lightning  in Your womb.
>   You indeed are the seasons and the seas. You  indeed are without
>   beginning; You exist as the Omnipresent,  from whom have sprung all
>   the worlds. "

(Svetasvatara Upanishad 4.4)

Answer (score 3):

Krishna says in the Gita, chapter 9, verses 4-6 (Swami Nikhilananda translator):

> By Me, in My unmanifested form, are all things in this universe pervaded. All beings exist in Me, but I do not exist in them.
>
> And yet the beings do not dwell in Me--behold, that is My divine mystery. My Spirit, which is the support of all beings and the source of all things, does not dwell in them.
>
> As the mighty wind blowing everywhere ever rests in the aksha, know that in the same manner all beings rest in Me.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, everything is God. Even right now, in whatever condition you are, in this condition also You are God. Supreme Shiva involves in five activities -

1. Emanation (Srishti).
2. Re- Absorption (SamhAra).
3. Concealment (Vilaye).
4. Maintenance (Sthiti).
5. Grace (Anugrah).

Now, Even after forgetting his real nature, Lord Shiva in the form of Jiva keeps doing these 5 activities.

> Even in this condition (of the empirical
>   self), he (the individual) does the five krtyas
>   (deeds) like Him (i.e. like Siva). Pratyabhijna Hridyam Sutra 10. 
>   **Commentary by AchArya KshemrAj**: When the great Lord who is consciousness (lit. whose form
>   is consciousness) entering into the sphere of the body, prana etc. on the occasion of the attention becoming external, makes
>   objects like blue etc. appear in definite space, time etc. then with
>   reference to appearance in definite space, time etc., **it is His
>   act of emanation (srastrta)**. With reference to the appearance
>   of the objects in another space, time etc., **it is His act
>   of withdrawal or absorption (samhartrta)**. With reference
>   to the actual (continuity of the) appearance of blue etc., **it is
>   His act of maintenance (sthdpakata)**. With reference to
>   its appearance as different, **it is His act of concealment
>   (vilayakarita)**. With reference to the appearance of every
>   thing as identical with the light (of consciousness), **it is His
>   act of grace (anugrahitrta)**. As to how the Lord is always
>   the author of the fivefold act, I have extensively demonstrated
>   in Spandasandoha. Thus this authorship of the fivefold act
>   occurring within one's own personal experience, if pursued
>   steadily with firm understanding, reveals the Lord's greatness
>   to the devotee. Therefore, those who always ponder over this
>   (fivefold act of the Lord), knowing the universe as an unfoldment
>   of the essential nature (of consciousness), become
>   liberated in this very life. This is what the (sacred) tradition
>   maintains (ityamnatah).