# What scriptures describe peacocks producing children through tears?

Tags: scripture, krishna, animals

A Rajasthan High Court judge recently made [the following statement](http://www.dnaindia.com/india/report-pushpa-i-hate-tears-twitter-loses-it-over-rajathan-hc-judge-s-sanskari-peacock-comments-2457099):

> Peacock is a Bramhachari and it does not have sex with a peahen. The peahen gets pregnant drinking the tears of the peacock. Even lord Krishna carried the feather of a peacock on his head.

The judge was roundly mocked for this, but I think he is conveying a Hindu concept.  Here's what [this article](http://www.india.com/news/india/do-you-know-why-lord-krishna-wears-a-peacock-feather-on-his-crown-1430810/) says:

> There is a mythological belief (albeit false) that peacocks do not use sex for reproduction but rather, the peahen drinks the tears of the peacock to conceive. Thus, Krishna is as pure as a peacock and that is what the feather signifies.

And here is what [this religious discourse](http://pbks.info/Website%20written%20materials/murlis/vcd146-gp.pdf) by a Swami named Shiv Baba says:

> Peacock is even today considered the National Bird of India. Why is it considered so? Why is not any other bird taken as the example. Any other bird could have been chosen as the national bird. Because, all other birds procreate by sexual contact. Only Peacock (male) is such an unusual bird. That the peahen (morni ) swallows the tear drops of the Peacock ( mor ) dancing in stately courtship around her. Then the peahen becomes pregnant. It shows that even today the example of such a bird prevails in this creation. And that same bird is considered as the National Bird of India.

So my question is, are there any scriptures which describe peahens getting pregnant from the tears of peacocks?  This is similar to the phenomena discussed in my question [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/15583/36).

Comment: Oh it's funny, Peacocks are like normal birds, I don't think so it has any special feature for producing child through tears, it's a Myth. please provide If there is any proof for strengthening this statement?

Comment: It's really funny -  "**Peacock is BrahmaChari**". The Judge and Swami should watch this - https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=erL7JHnzqww . (This video is not intended to post pornographic scenes. It is just a video showing Peacock copulating.)